# How to turn off debug notifications in workmanager? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I can't get the debug notifications to stop being sent. I've tried setting isInDebugMode to false and also tried completely removing that line, but it keeps sending me notifications (also they seem to send twice). Am I missing something?

This is the relevant code:

```
void main()
{
  runApp(PromotionProvider(
    child: MaterialApp(
      title: 'Price Point',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(elevation: 0.0)
      ),
      home: Home(),
    ),
  ));
  Workmanager.initialize(
    callbackDispatcher, 
    isInDebugMode: false, // this does not work
  );
  Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask(
    "1",
    notificationTask,
    frequency: Duration(minutes: 30),
    constraints: Constraints(
      requiresCharging: false,
      networkType: NetworkType.connected,
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Had the same issue, and eventually I disabled them by going to my device Settings -> Apps -> <my app> -> notifications. Hope it helps.

Comment: did you manage to find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you turn off debug mode in **right** work manager initializer.
I had same issue, almost give up, but then i realized that i had two initializers and fixed wrong one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade to the latest version of workmanager